# How to find $x$ out $x\%100+x\%(x\%100)+x\%(x\%(x\%100))...=a$?

Tags: polynomials, percentages

$$x\%100+x\%(x\%100)+x\%(x\%(x\%100))...=a$$
It repeats $b$ times.

$a$ is known.

$b$ is known.

How to find $x$?

I am not sure I formatted right, so I note that $x\%100$ means $x$ percent of $100$. Let me know, if something is wrong.

Equations are polynomials, examples:
$$x=a$$
$$\frac{x^2}{100}+x=a$$
$$\frac{x^4}{1000000}+\frac{x^2}{100}+x=a$$
$$\frac{x^8}{100000000000000}+\frac{x^4}{1000000}+\frac{x^2}{100}+x=a$$
$$\frac{x^{16}}{1000000000000000000000000000000}+\frac{x^8}{100000000000000}+\frac{x^4}{1000000}+\frac{x^2}{100}+x=a$$

In according to Galois Theory, it may have solution formula, quote:

> The formulas for the solutions of all look like towers: using square-roots, square-roots of square-roots, or cube-roots of square-roots, and so on upwards.

I need to find $x$ using solution formula, not by numerical methods like checking for each number to get approximate solution.

I note, if $x$ is $50\%$, it is easy to find, example:

$50+25+12.5=85.5$

$100-(87.5)=12.5$

$100-(87.5-12.5)=25$

$100-(87.5-12.5-25)=50$